# Determine if a folder exists with a $path variable

Tags: powershell

I am brand new to shell scripting and have what I assume is a simple problem which I can't solve - this is the first script I have written, so I may not correct with some of my terminology.

I'm working on a basic script that essentially creates folders and moves files into them using keywords within the file name. One of the parts of the code is to check whether the folder exists first before creating it.

So the code is:

```
$TestFolder = 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxx'
"Test to see if folder [$TestFolder]  exists"
if (Test-Path -Path $TestFolder) {
    "You already have this folder"
} else {
    "Folder has been created"
    mkdir Folder1
```

I've just removed the path in the first line but you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do.

This part of code is repeated three times, for three different folders. My question is, having already prompted the user for the folder they wish to 'tidy up' earlier in the code - with this:

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the file path you wish to organise'
[int]$totalSize = 0
cd $path
```

I want to be able to use the $path variable with a different folder extension to check if each different folder exists in the current path?

Something along the lines of:

```
$TestFolder = 'Current path\TestFolder 1'
```

Is there a way to do this?

I hope this all makes sense, as I said this is all brand new to me.

**EDIT: Using the help below, I altered the code to the following:**

```
$TestFolderChild = Join-Path $TestFolder 'TestFolder1'
"Check to see if this folder [$TestFolder]  exists"
if (Test-Path -Path $TestFolder) {
    "You already have this folder"
} else {
    "No. Folder has now been created"
    mkdir TestFolder1
}
```

This seemed to work yesterday but I'm not getting a

```
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

Comment: Use `Join-Path` to combine path segments: `$TestFolderChild = Join-Path $TestFolder 'TestFolder 1'`.

Comment: Perfect! That worked and I've learnt something. Appreciate your help and quick response.

Comment: Thanks for this, that seemed to have solved it but now for some reason I'm getting the following error `Check to see if the []  exists
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.` I've updated the question.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem where you assign `$TestFolder`. This code isn't included in the updated sample, so I can't tell more about that.

Comment: The next part of the code, moves files into the folders based on certain keywords in the title (the abs$ variable is assigned certain keywords) `$source = $PSScriptRoot
$dest = $TestFolder

Get-ChildItem -recurse ($source) -include ($abs) | move-Item -Destination ($dest)`